# Combine project from two separate repositories into one

Tags: git, github

I have a project that was downloaded from a GitHub repository and then added to a new repository also on GitHub, where development continued. How do I add the changes in the new repo to the old repo while preserving commits history.

Comment: It very much depends on how exactly you "added to a new repository." If you correctly forked (https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) the repo, you should be able to just submit a pull request (https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/).

Comment: Unfortunately the project was downloaded as a zip and then added to a new, completely separate repo. It was not forked so a pull request will not work.

Comment: The "old repo" might have guidelines in their documentation on submitting code to them. If not, you could try contacting them and see if they are interested. As a last resort, you could properly fork their repo and maintain yourself a forked version of the code.